# Django Dynamic Links NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, html, django, url, dynamic

I'm trying to dynamically create pages based on the movie title of the link clicked. I keep getting an error though when I try to set the link though "u'app_name' is not a registered namespace"

my index.html looks like this and it works when the link isn't set:

```
{% for movie in movies %}
        <li data-id="{{ movie.id }}"><a href="{% url 'app_name:detail' movie_title%}"><span class="title">{{ movie.title }}</span> ({{ movie.year }}) - {{ movie.genre}}<a class="delete">X</a></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

my views.py for the dynamic url pages look like this:

```
def detail(request, movie_title):
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'movie_object':movie_object})
```

my urls.py for this specific section looks like this:

```
url(r'(?P<movie_title>[_\w+])$', views.detail, name='detail')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
return render(request, 'detail.html', {'movie_object':movie_object})
```

movie_object did not correspond with any of the fields for the movie object